# What do I get from playing a Seasonal character without RoS?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have recently started playing Diablo 3 again, and have discovered a "Seasonal" Character choice. Upon investigation, the main focus is to reward the player after achieving certain things within the game. However, 2 of these goals require the Expansion ("Adventure Mode"); which I don't have.

Without the Expansion, what do I get from playing a Seasonal Character *specifically* (that is not included in the base Expansion like extra classes etc)?

Comment: I didn't think it would even be possible to play seasons with no adventure mode.

Comment: @lI I have already started playing the character, nothing has stopped me from doing so; and after [playing with the character for a while](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281157/do-seasonal-characters-nerf-the-game) I have achieved a couple of the Seasonal achievements, though not the Season-specific ones (there is one to reach level benchmarks - 10; 20 etc, which I have not been able to achieve even though my character is level 50)

Comment: @Ben This question seems to be primarily opinion based and will likely be closed. There are benefits and drawbacks to playing a seasonal  character. The benefits are that it's fun to start again and there are some unique seasonal items. The drawbacks are that it's temporary.

Comment: @Coomie I would argue that this would be the case if I had the Expansion (which I mentioned in the question that I don't), meaning that half of the benefits are irrelevant since I cannot achieve the requirements for the rewards. Additionally, the question is asking "what do I get from this", which I don't see as an opinion-based question - you have already (partially) provided the answer - the unique items that in my case are unachievable.

Comment: FWIW, Adventure Mode makes the game worthwhile.

Comment: Also, I don't think this is a duplicate because the answer is different from the linked question, which doesn't talk about seasons at all.

Comment: For the close voter(s), I don't see how this is "unreleased" or "illegal content". The game is legit, and these features, while inaccessible to those without the Expansion, are still featured in the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only a few things that requires you to play Seasons to obtain:

1. New portraits
2. 1 Additional stash tab
3. New seasonal pet

Since these are all tied to the season journey, which is primarily adventure mode focused, there is no benefit of you playing seasons when you don't own the expansion pack (as you have noted).

Previously, there were season only legendaries but that has been removed since [Patch 2.4](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/19993875/patch-240-preview-items-and-sets-12-18-2015):

> As you may have heard, we’re removing Season-exclusive Legendaries from the game.

Comment: Basically, it's just the experience of starting the game fresh, with nothing unlocked yet.

Comment: The portraits do stay over from season to season, so you can use them even on fresh characters in a new season. You also get certain transmogs in some of the seasons.